# Oracle Data Pump Export

Tags: oracle, datapump, expdp

If I want to export all the tables in a schema, can I just specify the schema parameter in the parfile or do I also need to list out all the tables individually in the tables parameters? I tried specifying just the schema parameter but the export keeps failing, so I want to confirm whether there is another mistake I am making or if it's because you need to explicitly specify the tables that you want to export.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to specify the `schemas` parameter.

```
expdp \'/ as sysdba\' schemas=siddhu
```

If you want to export only the tables, you can also add `include=table`:

```
expdp \'/ as sysdba\' schemas=siddhu include=table
```

The above exports the tables with indexes and triggers, but it skips procedures, sequences and other objects not directly related to tables.

Comment: Thanks! The requirements ended up changing so I didn't get to try out your solutions, but will definitely keep it in mind for the future. I never used the include parameter, so will read up on that.